# Как вывести все данные из колонки в базе данный sqlite3 при условии что некоторые значения NULL

Tags: python, sqlite3

[image]

Как из колонки bellang вывести все данные без NULL
Пробовал

```
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT bellang FROM '{people_id}'""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Что ожидаемо выводится [(None,), (9,), (5,), (7,)]

Нужно чтобы выводилось 9 5 7

`

Comment: `... WHERE bellang IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: а как убрать скобки

Comment: и при жтом выводить все числа

Comment: `print(*(item for item, in cursor.fetchall() or []), sep='\n')`